# Função para inverter uma string

Tags: c, string, funções

Tentei fazer uma função a fim de inverter uma string mas o programa sempre retorna
(null).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

char reverse(char string[])
{
   int length, i;

   length = strlen(string);

   char reverse_string[length];

   for(i=0; i<length; i++)
   {
      reverse_string[i] = string[(length - i) - 1];
   }

   return reverse_string;
}

int main()
{
   char string[50];

   gets(string);

   printf("%s", reverse(string));

   return 0;
}
```

Pensei que pudesse estar colocando o caractere '\0' na primeira posição de reverse_string, mas eu adicionei o "-1" na operação e mesmo assim o programa sempre retorna (null). Se alguém souber o que está acontecendo e puder dar uma dica, eu agradeço!

Answer (score 3):

O problema é que a tua função retorna um `char` mas `reverse_string` é um vetor, o correto seria retornar `char*`. Além disso, você esqueceu de marcar o final da string convertida com o terminador nulo `'\0'`.

```
char* reverse(const char string[])
{
    int length, i;
    length = strlen(string);
    char *reverse_string = malloc(length + 1); // +1 para o terminador nulo

    for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        reverse_string[i] = string[(length - i) - 1];
    }
    reverse_string[length] = '\0'; //terminador nulo no fim da string
    return reverse_string;
}
```

Nota que `reverse_string` tem que ser dinamicamente alocado. Caso contrário você estaria retornando o endereço para um vetor que já foi destruído. E não se esqueça que tens que libertar a memória.

```
int main() { 
    char string[50];

    gets(string);
    char* reversed = reverse(string);
    printf(reversed);
    free(reversed); //libertar a memória
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Há vários problemas no código apresentado:

- O tipo de retorno da função `reverse()` está `char`. Se pretende
  retornar uma string tem de ser `char*`.
- A string `reverse_string[]` é alocada na pilha dentro da função
  `reverse()`, por isto a string não sobreviverá ao término da execução
  da função. O valor de retorno de `reverse()` será um ponteiro
  inválido.
- A função `strlen()` calcula o tamanho da string sem incluir o
  terminador `'\0'`. É preciso adicionar o `'\0'` após o último
  caractere.

Duas alternativas de implementação seriam:

1. Alocar a string no heap, utilizando `malloc()` e devolver o ponteiro
   para a string. Fazendo isto, a string sobrevive para além do escopo
   da função e deve depois ser liberada usando `free()`.
2. Adicionar um parâmetro na função `reverse()` e passar para este
   parâmetro uma string já alocada para receber a string invertida.
   Neste caso a string a ser passada como parâmetro pode ser alocada
   normalmente na pilha dentro do `main()`.

A seguir a implementação destas duas variantes, `reverse_1()` e `reverse_2()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* reverse_1(char string[])
{
  // armazena o tamanho da string sem o terminador '\0'
  int length = strlen(string);

  // aloca espaço no heap
  char* reverse_string = malloc((length + 1) * sizeof(char));

  // inverte a string
  for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
       reverse_string[i] = string[length - i - 1];

  // coloca o terminador '\0'
  reverse_string[length] = '\0';

  return reverse_string;
}

void reverse_2(char string[], char reverse_string[])
{
  // armazena o tamanho da string sem o terminador '\0'
  int length = strlen(string);

  // inverte a string
  for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
       reverse_string[i] = string[length - i - 1];

  // coloca o terminador '\0'
  reverse_string[length] = '\0';
}

int main()
{
  char s[50];
  gets(s);

  // teste de reverse_1
  char* rs1 = reverse_1(s);
  printf("reverse_1: %s\n", rs1);
  free(rs1);

  // teste de reverse_2
  char rs2[50];
  reverse_2(s, rs2);
  printf("reverse_2: %s\n", rs2);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode inverter uma string *inplace* sem fazer uso de nenhuma função da biblioteca padrão, fazendo uso **apenas** de [aritmética de ponteiros](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ponteiro_(programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)#Aritm%C3%A9tica_de_ponteiros_em_C_e_C++), veja só:

```
void reverse( char str[] )
{
    char * ptr = str;

    while( ptr && *ptr )
        ptr++;

    for( ptr--; str < ptr; str++, ptr-- )
    {
        *str = *str ^ *ptr;
        *ptr = *str ^ *ptr;
        *str = *str ^ *ptr;
    }
}
```

Testando:

```
#include <stdio.h>  /* printf() */


void reverse( char str[] )
{
    char * ptr = str;

    while( ptr && *ptr )
        ptr++;

    for( ptr--; str < ptr; str++, ptr-- )
    {
        *str = *str ^ *ptr;
        *ptr = *str ^ *ptr;
        *str = *str ^ *ptr;
    }
}


int main( void )
{
    char txt[] = "O rato roeu a roupa do rei de Roma";

    reverse( txt );

    printf("%s\n", txt );

    return 0;
}
```

Saída:

```
amoR ed ier od apuor a ueor otar O
```

Veja funcionando do [Ideone](https://ideone.com/kKzK66)

Answer (score -2):

bom dia,

Exemplo de uma função para inverter uma string:

```
            string novaStr=string.Empty;
            string strOriginal;
            int i;

            strOriginal = "TesteInverter";

            for (i = strOriginal.Length-1; i >=0; i--)
            {
                novaStr += strOriginal[i];
            }

            Console.WriteLine(novaStr);
```

Comment: Ricardo, sua resposta não ajuda a resolver o problema específico da pergunta e ainda postou um código em outra linguagem, tente dar uma resposta mais direciona para o problema da pergunta